# Is it possible to add ip address to dnsmasq.conf instead of url

Tags: ubuntu, bind, dnsmasq

I'm very novice on this so please answer if you can.

Is it possible to add ip address instead of url/domain to `dnsmasq.conf` file

Here is an example of what I tried.

```
bind-dynamic
bogus-priv
domain-needed
log-facility=-
local-ttl=60
address=/100.100.100.18/95.0.0.0
```

I've tested `address=/google.com/95.0.0.0` and it works

> *ip addresses are masked in this example

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not remap one IP address to another via DNS.

If some application has just an IP address then it will not use DNS at all to try and connect (it may still do a reverse lookup for logging/security reasons, but not to connect).

You could do it via iptables and DNAT

Comment: Can you please provide an example of how to do it with iptables

Comment: Why not have a go first and ask a new question if you get stuck